# How to navigate in auto completion menu, when arrows are disabled in .vimrc

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion

Reason for my question: It's not the first time I have cancelled my arrow keys in vim, and the improvments in my typing is again **tremendous**. I wish to keep arrow keys non effective inside vim.

HOWEVER: Like the last time, I stumble on the same thing that made me remove the arrow disabling.

I cannot navigate between the proposals of autocompletion. I simply can't if my arrows are "cancelled". Hjkl are taken as letters, not move commands here.

what should be corrected in my `.vimrc` file ?:

```
noremap  <Up> ""
noremap! <Up> <Esc>
noremap  <Down> ""
noremap! <Down> <Esc>
noremap  <Left> ""
noremap! <Left> <Esc>
noremap  <Right> ""
noremap! <Right> <Esc>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> for the previous/next item on the list.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question after several years as I have been using this key combination for some time

As said in previous answer:

- Ctrl-N: Move the selection down to the next suggestion
- Ctrl-P: Move the selection up to the previous suggestion

It can also be practical to use  in the same manner:

- Tab: Cycle through the available completions (forward)
- Shift-Tab: Cycle through the available completions (backward)

But I would like to add that these other two are just extremely useful, namely the C-Y for validation

- C-Y: Accept the current selection and insert it into the buffer
- C-L: Refresh the suggestions (in case they change dynamically)

I used to continue typing after selecting with Ctrl-P Ctrl-N or Tab Shift-Tab, like Enter or anything, which in many case forced me to do a correction: Ctrl-Y just accept the current selection as is

Of course Esc just close the current selection menu without selecting anything